# JMeter BackendListenerClient sends SampleResults too slow

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

We wrote a custom BackendListenerClient which extends AbstractBackendListenerClient.  It sends data to our backend api, but we should wait 20-30s to get the first set of samples. Is there any way to improve performance?

Here is log:

```
1 2019-01-15 11:32:49,117 INFO o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_EN
...
92 2019-01-15 11:32:57,513 INFO c.c.p.MyBackendListener: start sending metrics(Empty)
...
2019-01-15 11:33:15,534 INFO c.c.p.MyBackendListener: start sending metrics(100 samples)

Any ideas?

Thanks
```

Answer (score -1):

If you "wrote" it - my expectation is that you should know how to amend the interval.

For JMeter built-in listeners it's configurable via the following properties:

- `backend_graphite.send_interval` - for the [GraphiteBackendListenerClient](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/visualizers/backend/graphite/GraphiteBackendListenerClient.html)
- `backend_influxdb.send_interval` - for the [InfluxdbBackendListenerClient](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/visualizers/backend/influxdb/InfluxdbBackendListenerClient.html)

So if you copied and pasted existing JMeter code - it might be the case the listener you "wrote" respects this or that property. The properties can be defined either via [*user.properties* file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) or passed via [`-J` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)

Comment: send_interval is the interval between sending metrics, in my case is 3s. I am saying about getting 1st set of results in BackendListenerClient from JMeter.

Comment: The aforementioned classes rely on [ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) function where JMeter developers specify initial delay and period.